# Pagos con MercadoPago en PlayStore

Tags: android, mercadopago

estoy viendo de hacer una integración de MercadoPago en una app de peididos, y necesito procesar los pagos.
El uso de MercadoPago, no va encontra de las polticias del PlayStore de Google?
Ya que en una parte indica que los medios de pagos disponibles son los de Google. pero no se si esto hace referencia a solo cosas digitales y/o suscripciones en la app.

Comment: eso es para comprar apps y contenido digital(musica, videos, libros..etc).. puedes hacerlo como tu desees

Comment: Bienvenido ArSk8., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!